# Increment attribute value xslt

Tags: xslt

I have been trying to increment attribute value of following xml. Please help where I am wrong in getting desired result.

Input xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<GetProratedPriceInput xmlns="http://www.BRMProration.org">
   <ProductsInfo>
      <START_T>2015-07-28T18:07:07.561</START_T>
      <END_T>2015-07-28T18:07:07.561</END_T>
   </ProductsInfo>
   <ProductsInfo>
      <START_T>2015-07-28T18:07:07.561</START_T>
      <END_T>2015-07-28T18:07:07.561</END_T>
   </ProductsInfo>
   <ProductsInfo>
      <START_T>2015-07-28T18:07:07.562</START_T>
      <END_T>2015-07-28T18:07:07.562</END_T>
   </ProductsInfo>
</GetProratedPriceInput>
```

XSLT which I am using.

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="counter">
      <xsl:value-of select="0"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <abc:inputFlist>
      <xsl:for-each select="/ns2:GetProratedPriceInput/ns2:ProductsInfo">
        <abc:RESULTS elem="{$counter}">
          <abc:END_T>
            <xsl:value-of select="ns2:END_T"/>
          </abc:END_T>
          <abc:START_T>
            <xsl:value-of select="ns2:START_T"/>
          </abc:START_T>
          <xsl:variable name="counter">
            <xsl:value-of select="$counter + 1"/>
          </xsl:variable>
        </abc:RESULTS>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </abc:inputFlist>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Ouput from this xslt:

```
<abc:inputFlist xmlns:abc="http://xmlns.oracle.com/abc/schemas/BusinessOpcodes">
      <abc:RESULTS elem="0">
      <abc:END_T>2015-07-28T18:07:07.561</abc:END_T>
      <abc:START_T>2015-07-28T18:07:07.561</abc:START_T>
   </abc:RESULTS>
   <abc:RESULTS elem="0">
      <abc:END_T>2015-07-28T18:07:07.561</abc:END_T>
      <abc:START_T>2015-07-28T18:07:07.561</abc:START_T>
   </abc:RESULTS>
   <abc:RESULTS elem="0">
      <abc:END_T>2015-07-28T18:07:07.562</abc:END_T>
      <abc:START_T>2015-07-28T18:07:07.562</abc:START_T>
   </abc:RESULTS>
</abc:inputFlist>
```

but Desired output is as below:

```
<abc:inputFlist xmlns:abc="http://xmlns.oracle.com/abc/schemas/BusinessOpcodes">
      <abc:RESULTS elem="0">
      <abc:END_T>2015-07-28T18:07:07.561</abc:END_T>
      <abc:START_T>2015-07-28T18:07:07.561</abc:START_T>
   </abc:RESULTS>
   <abc:RESULTS elem="1">
      <abc:END_T>2015-07-28T18:07:07.561</abc:END_T>
      <abc:START_T>2015-07-28T18:07:07.561</abc:START_T>
   </abc:RESULTS>
   <abc:RESULTS elem="2">
      <abc:END_T>2015-07-28T18:07:07.562</abc:END_T>
      <abc:START_T>2015-07-28T18:07:07.562</abc:START_T>
   </abc:RESULTS>
</abc:inputFlist>
```

Please help what is wrong with increment counter variable.

Thanks for all the help.

Comment: As a matter of interest, did you try searching for "Increment attribute value xslt" before posting your question? It gives 18 hits, all of which (from a quick look) explain where you are going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables in XSLT are immutable, and cannot be changed. In your code you are simply defining a new variable which "shadows" the previous variable, but it will actually go out of scope immediately at the end of each `xsl:for-each` block

You don't need to use a variable at all here. You can make use of the `position()` function to keep a track of the count. Just change the line `<abc:RESULTS elem="{$counter}">` to this:

```
 <abc:RESULTS elem="{position() - 1}">
```